# IIS 7.5 ASP.NET HttpModule - Setting Response.Filter results in chunked encoding

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, httpmodule, content-length

I'm trying to create a HttpModule that changes the `Response.Filter` like so
(for this demonstration just set the filter back to itself):

```
public class ContentTrafficMonitor : IHttpModule
{
  public void Init( HttpApplication context )
  {
     context.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
  }

  private static void OnBeginRequest( object sender, EventArgs e )
  {
     var application = (HttpApplication) sender;
     application.Response.Filter = application.Response.Filter;
  }
```

}

Doing so sets the transfer encoding of the response to chunked, rather than using the `Content-Length` header.

If I remove the line where the `Response.Filter` is set, the response does have the `Content-Length` header. Our application depends on the `Content-Length` header, is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: i have this problem too. does anybody have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, setting the filter interferes with the normal buffering of the output, hence the output is now chunked.

Maybe you could imitate the behaviour by having your filter read till end, ie get all the output & set the content length header based on what you've read before you write everything read out.

It's only a guess though I'm afraid.

Simon